# Copying a java.util.Stack in Java

Tags: java, copy, stack

I'm looking for a proper way to copy `java.util.Stack` in Java.

`Stack` doesn't seem to have a copy constructor, and the only thing I have managed to find in the documentation that might do what I want is the `clone` method.

However, if I write

```
Stack<Integer> stack = (Stack<Integer>) oldstack.clone();
```

The compiler gives me a warning about unchecked types.

Is there a "proper" way for me to copy a `Stack`? If not what would be the most sensible thing to do here? I would prefer not to have any warnings, and I feel a little silly iterating and copying over values (although the later might turn out to be the most sensible thing to do).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `addAll`, I guess:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack();
stack.addAll(oldStack);
```

However, the documentation notes you should use a Deque in preference to the Stack class and there you have what you want immediately:

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(oldStack);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using `clone`. The compiler gives you an error that you have an **unhandled** (not unchecked) exception `CloneNotSupportedException`. This is just the standard story with Java and its checked exceptions, it shouldn't be the reason not to use `clone`. While it is true that the whole `clone` mechanism is seen as archaic today and it is really implemented only by the oldest classes in Java's standard library, it does work for those classes and has the potential bonus of being more performant than the alternatives (native memory copying).